# ¿Cómo hacer un programa que pida al usuario un numero entero entre 0 y 999? El programa debe mostrar con letra el numero ingresado

Tags: c#

> Crear un programa de pida al usuario un número entero entre 0 y 999, el programa debe mostrar con letra el número ingresado, si el número proporcionado no se encuentra dentro del rango mostrar debe pedir otro número, si se ingresan tres valores fuera del rango la aplicación debe
> terminar.

```
        int numero;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero positivo");
        numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int centenas = numero / 100;
        int decenas = (numero - (centenas * 100))/10;
        int unidades = numero - (centenas * 100) - (decenas * 10);
        string texto = " ";

        Console.WriteLine("Centenas: " + centenas);
        Console.WriteLine("Decenas: " + decenas);
        Console.WriteLine("Unidades: " + unidades);

        switch (centenas)
        {
            case 0:
                texto = "";
                break;
            case 1:
                texto = "Ciento";
                break;
            case 2:
                texto = "Doscientos";
                break;
            case 3:
                texto = "Trecientos";
                break;
            case 4:
                texto = "Cautrocientos";
                break;
            case 5:
                texto = "Quinientos";
                break;
            case 6:
                texto = "Seiscientos";
                break;
            case 7:
                texto = "Setecientos";
                break;
            case 8:
                texto = "Ochocientos";
                break;
            case 9:
                texto = "Novecientos";
                break;
        }
        switch (decenas)
        {
               
            case 10:
                texto = "Diez";
                break;
```

Sólo nos dieron ésto pero no lo explicaron y no sé cómo continuarlo.

Actualmente en la consola sólo indica el número de unidades, decenas y centenas que conforman el número introducido.

Comment: Primero la validación: `if(numero > 0 && numero < 999)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente hace una comprobación del numero al principio, para saber si el numero tiene 1, 2 o 3 dígitos.
Seguidamente hace un switch case, es decir.
En caso de que sea 100, el programa entra en el case de (centenas), y te guarda en texto el cientos, doscientos trescientos, o incluso en el caso de que te devuelva 0, por ejemplo si le metes el 80, te guarda en el texto una cadena vacia.
De hay pasa al switch case de decenas, y tienes que hacer lo mismo que antes, me refiero:

```
switch (decenas)    
{
            case 0:
                texto = texto+"";
                break;
            case 1:
                texto = texto+" Diez";
                break;
            case 2:
                texto = texto+" Veinte";
                break;
            case 3:
                texto = texto+" Treinta";
                break;
            case 4:
                texto = texto+" Cuarenta";
                break;
            case 5:
                texto = texto+" Cincuenta";
                break;
            case 6:
                texto = texto+" Sesenta";
                break;
            case 7:
                texto = texto+" Setenta";
                break;
            case 8:
                texto = texto+" Ochenta";
                break;
            case 9:
                texto = texto+" Noventa";
                break;
        }
```

Y luego simplemente lo mismo con las unidades.
El texto lo igualo al texto + la nueva cadena, para que en caso de ser el 535, te coja el  texto = quinientos + texto = quinientos treinta.

Acuerdate de meter el limite entre 1 y 999 con un simple do while.

```
    int numero;

do {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero positivo");
        numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
} while (numero <= 0 and numero > 999)
```